Switching between translations of the Bible, looking up text
I have a document with scriptures listed, that I can call. (I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but it's based on this stackoverflow answer.)
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addcase[3]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\makeswitch[ScriptureVersionError]\dothis
\addcase\dothis{James 1:5}{If any man lack wisdom, let him ask of God...}
\addcase\dothis{John 11:35}{Jesus wept.}

\begin{document}
\dothis{James 1:5}

\dothis{John 11:35}

\dothis{SomethingInvalid 1:1}
\end{document}

This produces the expected:

Now, those are KJV (King James Version) translations of bible verses. I'd like to switch to other translations (such as NIV, New Inspired Version) with just one command at the top, so something like this (note: this doesn't work)
\documentclass{book}

\SPECIFYTRANSLATION{kjv}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addcase[3]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\makeswitch[ScriptureVersionError]\dothis
\addcase\dothis{James 1:5}{If any man lack wisdom, let him ask of God...}{If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God...}
\addcase\dothis{John 11:35}{Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.}

\begin{document}
\dothis{James 1:5}

\dothis{John 11:35}

\dothis{SomethingInvalid 1:1}
\end{document}

Notice I've added a second translation (NIV) in curly braces after the KJV translation. Then at the top if I do \SPECIFYTRANSLATION{kjv} then it should print the KJV strings, and if I do \SPECIFYTRANSLATION{niv} then it should print the NIV strings.
If I'm way off base and there is a better way to do this with lookup tables or something please let me know.
EDIT:
I should mention that I need >2 translations (e.g. KJV, NIV, NASB, ...). Specifically, in the case above if I want to add a NASB version then I would add a third argument to each reference:
\addcase\dothis{James 1:5}{If any man lack wisdom, let him ask of God...}{If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God...}{But if any of you lacks wisdom, let him ask of God...}
\addcase\dothis{John 11:35}{Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.}

Note that I've listed three above but there might be 5-10 translations in the end.

There is also the bibletext package that takes a different approach, it uses an external tool to fetch the text (only the KJV in this case) instead of storing the whole Bible in LaTeX. You could also take inspiration from the quran package, that does store the full text in the source, using separate files for easy maintenance and different versions (for example https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/quran/tex/qurantext-en.translation.def for English and https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/quran/tex/qurantext-simple.def for Arabic).

@Marijn thanks. However I actually need more fine-grained control than this -- for example when I type "James 1:5" I will want all the text up to a certain point, and then an ellipsis and then some text beyond a certain point. If I do indeed want the entire James 1:5 printed at a particular location in the document I planned to call one "James 1:5 full" and one "James 1:5 partial" or some other meaningful keywords. AFAICT bibletext will give me the whole verse, or at least not allow me to skip words and insert ellipses in their place.

One option is to use a boolean and to choose the content of the commands when they are defined. The \addcase command gets an extra argument, so \newcommand\addcase[4] instead of \newcommand\addcase[3], and if the KJV boolean is true you choose the third argument in the definition, else if the NIV boolean is true you choose the fourth argument.
\documentclass{book}
\newif\ifkjv
\newif\ifniv
\kjvfalse
\nivtrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addcase[4]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{%
\ifkjv#3\else\ifniv#4\fi\fi}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\makeswitch[ScriptureVersionError]\dothis
\addcase\dothis{James 1:5}{If any man lack wisdom, let him ask of God...}{If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God...}
\addcase\dothis{John 11:35}{Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.}

\begin{document}
\dothis{James 1:5}

\dothis{John 11:35}

\dothis{SomethingInvalid 1:1}
\end{document}

Note that the choice is made on definition of the csnames for each verse, so you cannot change the version in the middle of the document.
If you make sure that only one of the booleans is true then you can also write it in a simpler way without nested ifs. This makes it easy to add multiple cases, for example:
\newcommand\addcase[5]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{%
\ifkjv#3\fi%
\ifniv#4\fi%
\ifnasb#5\fi%
}}


Thanks! However I failed to mention that I will need more than two translations, so I don't think this works for me. But nice solution, thanks. Anyway I'll edit the question to say that I need something that works for >2 translations now

My apologies, this does indeed work with >2. To add a third translation e.g. NASB, I just make addcase[5], and use: \ifkjv#3\else\ifniv#4\else\ifnasb#5\fi\fi\fi and add a third translation to each addcase, like: {Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.}{Jesus wept.} . Thanks for your help!

@dnh37 you can also make it a bit simpler without else and nested if, see edit. A small risk with this is that if you set two booleans to true at the top (or three etc) then you will get two verses from both versions as output.

The way in which I do it is with the package etoolbox and a toggle. It works in the following way. A toggle X is created with \newtoggle{X}. It is set to true or false with \toggletrue{X} or \togglefalse{X} and used with \iftoggle{X}{Do this if true}{Do that if false}. Here it is an example applied to your case:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % Booleans

% King James Version IF TRUE and New Inspired Version IF FALSE
\newtoggle{kjv}
\toggletrue{kjv}   % King James Version
%\togglefalse{kjv} % New Inspired Version

\begin{document}

According to James 1:5,

\iftoggle{kjv}{If any man lacks wisdom, let him ask of God... (KJV)}{If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God... (NIV)}

\end{document}

If set to true, as above, it produces

I hope it helps.

Thanks! However I failed to mention that I will need more than two translations, so I don't think this works for me. But nice solution, thanks

You are welcome. To add more translations, you simply need to nest the toggles. Set \newtoggle{niv}, \togglefalse{niv} and \iftoggle{kjv}{If any man lacks wisdom, let him ask of God... (KJV)}{\iftoggle{niv}{If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God... (NIV)}{Transalation \# 3.}}. This will print Translation # 3. Best
